# Why does Chrome use `with` for inline events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If you take a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SBkmr/) in Chrome and click the Trigger text with the js console open you will see this:

[image]

What is the reason of all those `with` blocks and what is it's value?

Comment: This is how inline events are supposed to work.

Comment: @SLaks What is the value of `this[2]`, `this[1]` and `this[0]` then?

Comment: @SLaks do you know if this behavior is written down anywhere, or is it just stuff to keep scripts from 1997 running in modern browsers?  Dumping all the properties from the target element and the document into the scope seems a little ... odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me as if it's how the browser creates a function for the event handler when it's specified as an HTML "onclick" attribute.  I *think* what that does is:

- make an event handler function with a single parameter for the event object and your supplied code;
- make properties of the element (the `<a>` tag), an empty object (?), and the document object appear to be available symbols for the code in that function.

That is, `this[0]` is the `<a>` element itself, `this[1]` looks like an empty Object instance, and `this[2]` is the document object. What this means is that in code you write as part of an "onfoo" event handler attribute (and *not* code in any ordinary event handler bound from straight JavaScript code), it's possible to refer to the properties of the target element (the element for which you're setting the attribute) and the properties of the document element *as if they were present in the scope chain.*

If you change the code a little:

```
$('<a href=# onclick="console.log(baseURI);"> ...
```

then you get the value of the "baseURI" property of the `<a>` element. No need to prefix "baseURI" with anything that explicitly refers to the DOM node for the `<a>` element; it's just "there" as if it were declared with `var` in some enclosing scope.

(checking w3c specs now ...) *edit* — I haven't found anything that stipulates what symbols are supposed to be available to the script code in event handlers. This is really weird.

*edit again* — Firefox seems to do the same thing, though I don't see the explicit `with` statements anywhere.

Comment: Is there any chance that the `with` statements are an artifact of running in the console?  We know that the consoles introduct otherwise unnecessary `eval` statements, and I can imagine that this might be a similar mechanism, although I haven't really thought about exactly **why**.  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet well I don't know exactly where the `with` statements come from. The part that's freaking me out is the **effect** of the `with` statements, and that it's a behavior that Firefox does too.

Comment: It's standard behaviour (unfortunately). http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler

Answer (score 1):

`with` moves it's argument on top of scope stack. So it's even higher than global object, function params, etc. No idea why they use it. Perhaps it is a generated code.