# Why doesn't it execute this function？

Tags: javascript

alert is also a member of the window, why the alert function can be executed.What is their difference?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function close() {
      console.log('close function');
    }

    function alert() {
      console.log('alert function');
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="close()">close btn</button>
  <button onclick="alert()">alert btn</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because the name clashes with [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).

Comment: @AKX this seems to be the case, although I can't see why the other button doesn't clash with `window.alert()`

Comment: `close` being a property of `window` should not be an issue, its property descriptor is `{writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true, value: ƒ}` (in Firefox and Chromium), that tells the property can be overridden, which declaring a global function should do.

Comment: In your HTML code, you have defined a function named close, but the problem is that the window object in browsers already has a close method, which is used to close the current window or tab. Due to this, your custom close function is getting overshadowed by the built-in close method. 

To resolve this issue just rename your close method to somethibng else like myClose();

Comment: JavaScript provides an in-built function named close() and alert().When you create any user defined function then keep the name of the function different from the name of built in function.You need to just change both functions name in your code.

Comment: seems a special case, since alert() is working

Comment: `close` is actually [an interesting case](https://jsfiddle.net/2zat3kgc/) ...

Comment: It looks like this has something to do with how inline listeners are fetching references, when passing the declared function to `addEventListener`, [it works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/2zat3kgc/1/).

Comment: From [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler) I figured out (hopefully correctly) that the scope of inline listeners includes [the realm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) of `window`, that is the original window object source. This is why an inline listener finds the original `close` method instead of the globally declared function, althought the window method itself can be shadowed  (and actually is shadowed in your code).

Comment: See http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324935/why-does-chrome-use-with-for-inline-events, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599614/reserved-function-names-in-javascript